# Formatar Número em Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, number-format

Tenho a seguinte função que calcula e salva 2 dados no meu database, porém quero formatar kwhAparelho e totalAparelho de forma que não causem dízimas periódicas e de preferência desta forma ##,## ou ##.##, qual a melhor forma de fazê-lo?

```
void _calculoAparelho() {
double quantidade = double.parse(qtdControlled.text);
double horadia = double.parse(horadiaControlled.text);
double diames = double.parse(diamesControlled.text);
double potencia = double.parse(potenciaControlled.text);
double kwh = double.parse(controllerkwh.text);
// calculo kwh
double kwhAparelho = (potencia * horadia * diames * quantidade / 1000);
note.consumokwh = '$kwhAparelho';
// valor em reais
double totalAparelho = (kwhAparelho * kwh);
note.gasto = '$totalAparelho';  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essa pergunta está mais relacionada a Dart, do que Flutter em si.

Não sei se você quer arredondar o valor de acordo com as casas decimais, ou simplesmente formatar o número para obedecer a máscara ignorando as casas decimais.

Por exemplo o número 0.18941 e a máscara ##,##

- Apenas formatando: 00.18
- Arredondando e formatando: 00.19

A documentação é sua amiga, se você der uma olhada nesse método [toStringAsPrecision()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/num/toStringAsPrecision.html) da classe num, você consegue passar um valor int de precisão e ele irá te dar um valor formatado com a precisão necessária.

Utilizando ele `0.18941.toStringAsPrecision(2)`

- O retorno é: 0.19

[Rode um exemplo no DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/eb722507ab76e07a109bd644d2c8a9dd)

Agora para formatar esse valor de modo que em ambos lados do ponto flutuante (valor inteiro e valor decimal) obedeçam a máscara, pode ser usado a classe [NumberFormat](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html).
Esse precisa ser importado do pacote [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl), e por conta disso não roda pelo DartPad, mas segue o código:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat("00.00");
  double initialValue = num.parse(0.18941.toStringAsPrecision(2));
  double value = 0.19;

  print(formatter.format(initialValue));
  print(formatter.format(value));
}
```

O resultado do código vai ser:

**0.19**

**00.19**

Você precisa adicionar a dependência do pacote no pubspec.yaml

```dart
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.15.7
```